# how to install ioncube loader?

Tags: php, ioncube

I recieved this error:

> Site error: the file C:\wamp\www\html\news.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.1.dll to be installed by the site administrator.

Then I have obtained the proper file and pasted it in the HTML folder.
Nothing has changed.

What should I do?

Comment: How to solve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download DLL from ioncube site and set path into `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension = "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\ioncube\i_win_5.3.dll"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [IonCode loader](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php)

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ioncube+loader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-beta) however is your friend for these type of questions, just google IonCude loader and you get lots of results, the first being a link to their site...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run a PHP file which is encrypted by IonCube then you need to install IonCube Loader on your Server. IonCube Loader is a PHP extension which is used to run/execute PHP files which are encoded by IonCube Encoder.
For more information about on installing IoCube, here is a detailed article on [how to install ioncube locally](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/install-ioncube-loader-localhost.html)